# How do I fix Type error: 'function' does not support indexing

Tags: python, python-3.10

Below is the code. The error is: Type error: 'function' does not support indexing on line 12 in main.py. I've tried switching the variable, looking for other people who had this same question answered but to no success. I know I am doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what. The problem might not be on line 12 so if you find nothing wrong with line 12 pls check the other parts of the code.

```
import turtle
import time
import random
ct = 0  
tasks = [
  'probe',
  'O2',
  'spacewalk (E.V.A.)',
  'exersize',
  ]
oof = ['0', '1', '2', '3']
ooo = random.randint(len[oof]) #this is line 12


def taskslist():
  turtle.goto(-200,190)
  turtle.color('green')
  turtle.write('TASKS TO COMPLETE')

  for i in tasks:
    x = -200
    y = 179

    turtle.goto(x, y)
    turtle.hideturtle()

    turtle.write(tasks[0])
```

Comment: `len(oof)`  not `len[oof]`

Comment: Actually, why even have the list? Just do `random.randint(0, 3)`

Answer (score 1):

Indexing means the use of square brackets [], by which you access the nth element of a collection, in this case it is saying that len, which is a function, does not support indexing because you used len[oof] instead of len(oof). When using parenthesis you are passing oof as argument.